# JavaFX, How fill in the table

Tags: java, javafx

I have a table in `MS SQL server` that has `4` columns: `id`, `channel`, `movie`, `time`. Four possible rows:`HBO|Furious 7|12:15`, `HBO|Wimbledon|11:25`,`FOX|The Simpsons|7:00`,`FOX|Lucifer|9:01`. I have a class called `guide`:

```
public class guide {
private String channel;
private String movie;
private LocalTime time;
(...)
```

And a class called `gui`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class gui extends Application {

    Stage stage;
    Scene sceneMain;

    int nrOfChannels;
    List<String> channelsOnMain;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TableView<guide> tableMain = new TableView<>(loadMain());

        List<TableColumn<guide, String>> colChannelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfChannels; i++) {
            colChannelList.add(new TableColumn<guide, String>(channelsOnMain.get(i)));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < colChannelList.size(); i++){
            colChannelList.get(i).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<guide, String>("movie"));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < colChannelList.size(); i++)
            tableMain.getColumns().add(colChannelList.get(i));


        BorderPane paneMain = new BorderPane(tableMain);
        sceneMain = new Scene(paneMain);

        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setScene(sceneMain);
        stage.setTitle("TVguide");
        stage.show();
    }

    public ObservableList<guide> loadMain(){
        ObservableList<guide> mainList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        int numberOfChann = 0;
        try {
            handleDB dbMain = new handleDB();
            Connection myConnection = dbMain.connect_with_DB();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM main";
            ResultSet mainFromDB = dbMain.getFromSQL(myConnection, query);
            String tempChannel = "";
            channelsOnMain = new ArrayList<>();
            while (mainFromDB.next()) {
                if(mainFromDB.getString(3).toString() != null && !mainFromDB.getString(3).toString().isEmpty()) {
                    if(!mainFromDB.getString(2).equals(tempChannel)){
                        numberOfChann++;
                        tempChannel = mainFromDB.getString(2);
                        channelsOnMain.add(tempChannel);
                    }
                    mainList.add(new guide(mainFromDB.getString(2), mainFromDB.getString(3), new LocalTime(mainFromDB.getString(4))));//2-channel,3-movie,4-time
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        nrOfChannels = numberOfChann;
        return mainList;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have an `ObservableList<guide>` returned by the `loadMain()` method, so here

```
colChannelList.get(i).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<guide, String>("movie"));
```

It puts every movie in every column, and it's logical, but not my point. Is it possible to change this

```
for(int i = 0; i < colChannelList.size(); i++){
    colChannelList.get(i).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<guide, String>("movie"));
}
```

in order to have in a column `colChannelList.get(i)` `movie` properties that belong to object with particular `channel` ? 
In brief, I would like to have a table that in column `HBO` has `Furious 7` and `Wimbledon` and in column `FOX` has `The Simpsons` and `Lucifer`, not a column f.e. `HBO` that has every `4` movies, is it possible ?

Comment: the convention for naming in java says that class names should start with a capital letter! so you might want to call you class `Gui` or `GUI` (the second since it's actually an abbreviation, but thats a matter of preference..)